# Stripe: Can I send payment link received from Checkout Session object to customer in email.?

Tags: stripe-payments

In Stripe docs, it is mentioned you can create a pre-build checkout session which is hosted by Stripe. When response is returned from session creation you can send a redirect request to client with the link obtained for the session.
Instead of redirecting the client, I want to send the link in an email/whatsapp to the customer. I want to know is it safe to do so. Is there anything i need to keep in mind while doing this ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating a [Checkout Session](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions), the URL will [expire after 24 hours](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-expires_at) and it can only be used by a single user.

If you are creating a [Payment Link](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_links/payment_links), the URL won't expire and it also can be used by multiple users. Note that when a user clicks on the Payment Link URL, Stripe will automatically create a Checkout Session for that user.

So if you plan to share the link directly with your users (for example by email), I would recommend to use a Payment Link.

Comment: Hi Soma, thanks for answering the question. In PaymentLink option you have to create a product first in dashboard and add its reference in line items while creating payment link. But in checkout sessions you can create products on the fly while creating checkout sessions. In my application there are lot of combinations and I don't want to add each and every product to the dashboard. Is checkout sessions way to go then ?

Comment: My question is what problem PaymentLink product is solving which happened in Checkout Session product? What is pros and cons. If you know that would be very helpful. Thanks

Comment: The main differences: a Checkout Session link expire after 24 hours and can be used by a single user, a PaymentLink doesn't expire and can be used by multiple users. Also PaymentLinks can be created in the dashboard. So overall they are similar, but PaymentLinks are simpler (create it once and share it multiple times) and Checkout Session more flexible (more options available). Which one you choose is completely up to you.